# comparing time in sql server through hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, hibernate

I am trying to compare time through hibernate in SQL Server 2008.

The following code returns this error : `The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the less than or equal to operator.`

```
crit = session.createCriteria(ObdBlackoutHours.class);
Criterion start = Restrictions.le("blackoutStart", new Date());
        Criterion end = Restrictions.gt("blackoutEnd",new Date());
        List list = crit.add(Restrictions.conjunction().add(start).add(end))
                .list();
        if(list.isEmpty())
            return false;
        else 
            return true;
```

The table design is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[obd_blackout_hours](
[id] [int] NOT NULL,
[blackout_end] [time](7) NOT NULL,
[blackout_start] [time](7) NOT NULL)
```

I understand that the db contains only `10:17:37` and what I am passing is something like this `Thu Nov 14 10:17:37 IST 2013` which it is unable to compare. I tested the same code in `mysql` which seems to be working very fine. But `SQL Server 2008` is creating the problem. I also tried passing

`currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));`

and

`new ObdBlackoutHours(1,new Date(),new Date()).getBlackoutStart()`

instead of the just the Date() object. This also fails. How should I compare time and get results.

The following is the entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "obd_blackout_hours", schema = "dbo", catalog = "IVR_Data")
public class ObdBlackoutHours implements java.io.Serializable {

private int id;
private Date blackoutStart;
private Date blackoutEnd;
private Set<Service> services = new HashSet<Service>(0);

public ObdBlackoutHours() {
}

public ObdBlackoutHours(int id, Date blackoutStart, Date blackoutEnd) {
    this.id = id;
    this.blackoutStart = blackoutStart;
    this.blackoutEnd = blackoutEnd;
}

public ObdBlackoutHours(int id, Date blackoutStart, Date blackoutEnd,
        Set<Service> services) {
    this.id = id;
    this.blackoutStart = blackoutStart;
    this.blackoutEnd = blackoutEnd;
    this.services = services;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@Column(name = "blackout_start", nullable = false, length = 16)
public Date getBlackoutStart() {
    return this.blackoutStart;
}

public void setBlackoutStart(Date blackoutStart) {
    this.blackoutStart = blackoutStart;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@Column(name = "blackout_end", nullable = false, length = 16)
public Date getBlackoutEnd() {
    return this.blackoutEnd;
}

public void setBlackoutEnd(Date blackoutEnd) {
    this.blackoutEnd = blackoutEnd;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "obdBlackoutHours")
public Set<Service> getServices() {
    return this.services;
}

public void setServices(Set<Service> services) {
    this.services = services;
}

}
```

Comment: java.sql.Date or java.util.Date?

Comment: java.util.Date.
But it gives the same error with new java.sql.Time(new java.util.Date().getTime()) also. i.e. con not compare time and datetime

Comment: nobody has ever compared time in sql server???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the following blog:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/using-time-and-date-data-types-part-1-it-s-about-time/ba-p/383611

Need to add the following to your hibernate connection url string
I am not sure if it's true/false just play with it.
sendTimeAsDateTime=false

Comment: In my case even I use sendTimeAsDateTime=false in my connection url also not working.