# The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, hql

I have a variable type time in a column of a table of the database.
How can I compare this value in java with this field I mean can i use date, gregoriancalendar?
I've tried adn I still have this message, please can someone give me an advice

```
Date d2 = new Date();                      // timestamp now
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();       // get calendar instance
cal.setTime(d2);                           // set cal to date
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);            // set hour to midnight
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);                 // set minute in hour
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);                 // set second in minute
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);            // set millis in second
Date d3 = cal.getTime();   

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Asistencia> list = (List<Asistencia>) sessionFactory
.getCurrentSession()
.createQuery(
        "select new Asistencia( asis.idAsistencia,"
        + "asis.horaInicio, asis.horaFin) "
        + "from Asistencia asis "
        + "where :hour >= asis.horaInicio and :hour <= asis.horaFin")

.setParameter("hour", d3).list();
```

I also used between

```
where :hour between asis.horaInicio and asis.horaFin
```

and the mesage is the same:

```
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator.
```

The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator.

Here the class Asistencia:

```
public class Asistencia implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private long idAsistencia;
    private Date horaInicio;
    private Date horaFin;
    private int idAula;
    private int idCurso;
    private int idPeriodo;
    private Date fecha;

    public Asistencia (){
    }
    public Asistencia (long idAsistencia, Date horaInicio, Date horaFin){
          this.idAsistencia
          this.horaInicio = horaInicio;
          this.horaFin = horaFin;
    }
```

}

Comment: ready, I updated the post @oshingc

Comment: try using the @Temporal annotation in your entity.

Comment: Not sure if this will do, but try setting your parameter as a [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) variable instead.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the only problem was I'm using SQL Server 2008 and is necessary to put sendTimeAsDateTime=false in the connections properties.

Here a similar question.
[comparing time in sql server through hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970161/comparing-time-in-sql-server-through-hibernate)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error using SpringBoot(v2.2.2) and MSSQL server (jdbc7.4.1)  when calling a JpaRepository API passing null dates. This was first version Repository API

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t FROM MyEntity t WHERE "
 + " AND ( ?3 IS NULL OR ( ?3 IS NOT NULL AND t.fromDate<= ?3 ))"
 + " AND ( ?2 IS NULL OR ( ?2 IS NOT NULL AND t.toDate>= ?2 ))") 
List<MyEntity> getMyEntity(LocalDate fromDate, LocalDate toDate);
```

When calling API with null value for input dates i got the exception:

```
The data types date and varbinary are incompatible in the less than or equal to operator
```

I solved with a CAST:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t FROM MyEntity t WHERE "
 + " AND ( ?3 IS NULL OR ( ?3 IS NOT NULL AND t.fromDate<= CAST( ?3 AS date ) ))"
 + " AND ( ?2 IS NULL OR ( ?2 IS NOT NULL AND t.toDate>= CAST( ?2 AS date ) ))")
List<MyEntity> getMyEntity(LocalDate fromDate, LocalDate toDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without setting that sendTimeAsDateTime property, which is not available for the SQL Server drivers older than 3.0 (and some of us are stuck with what we have, for reasons), you could try to use a String instead of a date.  This worked for me using a PreparedStatement and I bet it would work in this scenario also. Change the last line of your first code block to:

```
.setParameter( "hour", new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(d3) ).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue when querying data by entity property of type `javax.time.LocalDate` via `spring-data-jpa` and `eclipselink` . Connection setting `sendTimeAsDateTime=false` didn't help. This was fixed by adding `spring-data-jpa` converter `<class>org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten.Jsr310JpaConverters$LocalDateConverter</class>` into the `persistence.xml` file. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue. My sql data type is `Time(7)` and each time I want to compare it via JPQL query, that error comes out. Connection string `sendTimeAsDateTime=false` didn't work. Adding `<class>org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten.Jsr310JpaConverters$LocalDateConverter</class>` into the `persistence.xml` also didn't work.

What I do is, store data `Time(7)` from sql into `String`, for example this is my table design on sql

```
StartTime   time(7)
```

In my java class I store that field into `String` variable

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableSchedule")
public class TableSchedulue implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9112498278775770919L;
    ....
    @Column(name = "StartTime")
    private String startTime;
    .....
}
```

When I use JPQL query like this (in repository)

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a "
            + "FROM TableSchedule a "
            + "WHERE a.startTime <= ?1 ")
    List<TableSchedulue > getTestData(String startTime);
```

Your string format must `HH:mm:ss`
It works. Hope it helps

CONS : Because in SQL the type is `Time(7)` so value `08:00:00` in SQL will become `08:00:00.0000000` in persistence so you need to parse it into your needs