# The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the equal to operator?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I got this error after I tried to delete table row based on the date, start and end time. I used onClick function to pass the Date, start and end time from the table row. Then I used Ajax to send these values. Here is my code:

```
<cfoutput query="qryView">
    <table>
       <tr>
           <td>#dateFormat(DateSch,"mm/dd/yyyy")#</td>
           <td>#timeFormat(Stime,"hh:mm tt")#</td>
           <td>#timeFormat(Etime,"hh:mm tt")#</td>
           <td onClick="deleteDate('#dateFormat(DateSch,"mm/dd/yyyy")#','#timeFormat(Stime,"hh:mm tt")#','#timeFormat(Etime,"hh:mm tt")#')">Delete</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</cfoutput>

<script>
    function deleteDate(DateSch,Stime,Etime){ 
        $.ajax(
        {
            type:'POST',
            url:'/AjaxFunction.cfc?method=deleteSchedule&returnformat=json',
            data:{'DateSch':DateSch,'Stime':Stime,'Etime':Etime},
            cache:false,
            success: function(data,x,xhrobj)
            {
                var Result = $.parseJSON(data);
                if($.trim(Result.STATUS) == '200'){
                    alert('Removed!');
                }else{
                    alert(Result.message); 
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And here is my delete Query:

```
<cfquery name="qryDelete" datasource="test">
    Delete From Table
    Where DateS = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#arguments.DateSch#">
    and Start = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#arguments.Stime#">
    and End = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#arguments.Etime#">
</cfquery>
```

First when I tried to click on the button delete I got an java script error like this:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list    
deleteDate('74','{ts '2015-12-10 00:00:00'}','1970-01-01 08:00:00.0','1970-01-01...
```

Then I put dateFormat around the date value that I'm passing and timeFormat around time values. That fixed that issue. Then I got an error after my Ajax call:

```
"The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the equal to operator"
```

My values that I sent in my arguments look like this:

```
DateSch 
12/10/2015
Etime   
08:25 AM
Stime   
08:00 AM
```

I do not know why I'm getting this error. I tried to convert these values with createDateTime function in coldfusion before I used them in the cfquery but that did not help. Does anyone know how I can fix this error/compare datetime with my values?

Comment: Um... did you verify the cfquery actually works first? If not, skip the ajax for now. Troubleshoot the query first, because if it does not work, the ajax definitely won't work either.  Test the cfquery on a separate page, with a few variables and the sample values above. What is the result - same error? If so, please add A) the *complete* error message your question (including line numbers and any generated SQL) and B) the data types for those three columns: DateS, Start, End. (I am assuming those are not the *actual* columns, since both "Start" and "End" are reserved words.).

Comment: I tested my cfquery and works fine just with values that I passed with ajax. For Date time I use example: '2015-12-11' that works, but this works fine too '12/11/2015'. For Start time I use ' 
08:00 AM' and End time '08:15 AM'. I named StartTime and EndTime those two columns in db. Also Data Types fro these three columns are date, time(7) and time(7). This is how my argument values are sent to cfc page  value = {"ETIME":"08:15 AM","STIME":"08:00 AM","DATESCH":"2015-12-11"}

Comment: I fixed the problem. Front of my arguments in Where clause I use CONVERT() and Then VARCHAR. Now my cfquery works fine.

Comment: If you must cast, avoid `varchar` since that results in implicit conversion, which can lead to wacky results in certain cases. Instead, use the same data type as on the left side of the operand.  I rarely use TIME columns. Typically I prefer to use a single date/time column for simpler querying, but try either the TIME( ..) function or CAST(... AS TIME).  *but this works fine too '12/11/2015'.* Yes, CF can parse most date strings automatically. Though it is has a pretty broad interpretation of values it "thinks" are dates and times, so validating date/time strings is usually a good idea.

Comment: FYI, rolled back to previous version so the existing comments and answer still make sense. Feel free to post your final code as an "answer".  Answering your own question is allowed on S.O..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always post the *complete* error message. The query you posted works fine with MySQL 5.6. So despite the "MySQL" tag, I have a strong suspicion you are actually using SQL Server, and that the full error message actually says:

> **[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]** The data types time and
>   datetime are incompatible in the equal to operator.

That error is usually caused by [submitting "time" values as "datetime" values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817540/the-data-types-datetime-and-time-are-incompatible-in-the-greater-than-or-equal-t). That causes an error because the query ends up trying to compare apples and oranges, ie time and datetime.

Some MS SQL Server drivers support disabling that behavior by adding [`sendTimeAsDateTime=false`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2010/04/08/using-time-and-date-data-types-part-1-what-time-is-it.aspx) to the DSN connection properties. Unfortunately, that does not seem to work with the core Adobe Database Drivers. As you discovered, you will need to use a cast or convert. However, do not use `varchar`. That will result in implicit conversion, which can lead to wacky results in certain cases. Instead, use the same data type as on the left side of the operand, ie `time`

```
<cfquery datasource="theDatasource">
    DELETE FROM TableName
    WHERE  DateSch = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#arguments.DateSch#">
    AND   STime = CAST(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#arguments.Stime#"> AS TIME) 
    AND   ETime = CAST(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#arguments.Etime#"> AS TIME)
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<cfquery name="qryDelete" datasource="test">
    Delete From Table
    Where DATEDIFF(DateS, <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#arguments.DateSch#">) = 0
    and TIMEDIFF(Start, <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#arguments.Stime#">) = 0
    and TIMEDIFF(End, <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#arguments.Etime#">) = 0
</cfquery>
```

I'm not familiar with ColdFusion, so I can't say for sure that the preceding is free of syntax errors. Additionally, you may have to change your date format to `YYYY-MM-DD` to keep MySQL happy.

Comment: I do not think that will help in this case, DateDiff will give me a which date1 is less than date2.

Comment: You're looking for `DateS = someotherdate`. Using **DATEDIFF**, you test for `DATEDIFF(DateS, someotherdate) = 0` when the two dates are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add ";sendTimeAsDateTime=false" to dataSource config if you are using spring mvc framework
Example :

```
<property name="url"
        value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=testdb;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;sendTimeAsDateTime=false" />
```